# Terraform s3_bucket_policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am using Terraform to build AWS environments and having an issue with s3 bucket polices and account.

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "awsbucketprodpolicy" {
    bucket = local.prodtbucket
    policy = jsonencode({
        Version = "2012-10-17"
        #Id = format("%s-policy", local.vaultbucket )
        Statement = [
            {
                #Sid = "prodpolicy"
                Effect = "Allow"
                Principal = "*" #aws_organizations_account.prodbucket.arn #"*"
                Action = "s3:CopyObject
        #["s3:CopyObject","s3:DeleteObject","s3:GetObject"]
                Resource = [
                    aws_s3_bucket.prodbucket.arn,
                    "${aws_s3_bucket.prodbucket.arn}/*",
                ]
            }
        ],
    })
}
```

I get an error with the Action. Error putting S3 policy: MalformedPolicy: Policy has invalid action. It works with "s3:8)" but not the exact actions.

Comment: The Terraform currently in your question isn't valid or runnable. Could you edit your question so that it forms a [mcve] please? At a minimum the `aws_s3_bucket_policy` should actually match what you are running when you get the error.

Answer (score 0):

Your policy key currently has statements in it that are commented out, which does not correctly encode into JSON. The `Action` line is also missing a quote.
Lastly, there is no policy action for the copyObject command, [according to this article](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-troubleshoot-copy-between-buckets/), you need at least listObject and getObject permission to do so

Cleaned up policy object:

```
{
        Version = "2012-10-17"
        Statement = [
            {
                Effect = "Allow"
                Principal = "*"
                Action = [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:PutObject",
                ]
                Resource = [
                    "${aws_s3_bucket.prodbucket.arn}/*"                    ]
            }
        ],
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. I have changed the code and get access denied but the same credentials are used to create the bucket and a user.

Comment: are you able to get the object from the aws console? If not, you need to go to your IAM user or role and give it permission to CreateBucket as well as the other actions listed above